# Y limit and Y tick does not appear on imagesc plot

Tags: matlab, plot, set, label, axis-labels

I have an 5x4000 array and I am using the imagesc function to get the density plot of this array. The only issue I have is than when I am modifying the Y_limit and Y_tick it either it does not show up in the plot or the the image does not appear on the plot! For your note, the X_tick and limit works fine! Here is the code that I am using:

```
imagesc(Array)
set(gca,'XLim',[0 4000])
set(gca,'XTick',[0:500:4000])
set(gca,'YLim',[22 26])
set(gca,'YTick',[22:26])
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `imagesc`, your x and y data are automatically selected to be the matrix column or row where your data point was found.  If you change your y-limits to be outside of this range then your data will disappear.  However, if you just want your y axis to be labelled from 22 to 26, then this should work:

```
Array = rand(5,4000);
imagesc(Array)

set(gca,'XLim',[0 4000])
set(gca,'XTick',[0:500:4000])
set(gca,'YLim',[0.5 5.5])
set(gca,'YTick',[1:5])
set(gca,'YTickLabel',[22:26])
```

[image]